# Prove that $\mathsf{A}\mathsf{G}^\mathrm{T}\mathsf{G}$ is a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Prove that $\mathsf{A}\mathsf{G}^\mathrm{T}\mathsf{G}$ is a positive semidefinite matrix, where
$\mathsf{G} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ and $\mathsf{A} = \mathrm{diag}(0,1,\dots,1,0) \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is wrong. Take $G$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix with all elements $1$. and take $x$ be the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
-4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then I think $x^\mathrm{T}\mathsf{A}\mathsf{G}^\mathrm{T}\mathsf{G}x$ is less than zero.

Comment: You answer is correct, but you should add transpose sign so multiplication make sense.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the matrix $x$.